# CSV Layout in Apache log4j2 generating only log statements from particular set of classes. How do we enable it from all classes?

Tags: java, csv, logging, struts2, log4j2

I recently enabled my log4j2 configuration to generate a CSV file from the loggers. The CSV file is generating fine. However, only the log statements from the web service client classes are realized in the CSV i.e. log statements from managers, action classes (Struts 2 Actions), Utility Classes, Mapper classes and web service request/response printing handlers are not being generated at all in the CSV file. What could be the reason for this?

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="infoLog.filename">/logs/info.log</Property>
    <Property name="debugLog.filename">/logs/debug.log</Property>
    <Property name="errorLog.filename">/logs/error.log</Property>
    <Property name="communicationLog.filename">/logs/communication.log</Property>
    <Property name="csvLog.fileName">/logs/csvLog</Property>
    <Property name="file-header">column1,column2,column3</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>

    <RollingFile name="csvFile" fileName="${csvLog.fileName}.csv"
    filePattern="${csvLog.fileName}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.csv">
    <BurstFilter level="WARN" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>
        <CsvParameterLayout delimiter="," header="${file-header}\n" />
        <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200" />
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="debugFile" fileName="${debugLog.filename}"
        filePattern="${debugLog.filename}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%-5p [%t] -%-10c (%L):-(%method) %m%n%throwable" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200" />
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="infoFile" fileName="${infoLog.filename}"
        filePattern="${infoLog.filename}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %X{userId} [%t] -%-10c (%-L):-(%method) %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200" />
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="errorFile" fileName="${errorLog.filename}"
        filePattern="${errorLog.filename}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %X{userId} [%t] -%-10c (%-L):-(%method) %m%n%throwable" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200" />
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="communicationLog" fileName="${communicationLog.filename}"
        filePattern="${communicationLog.filename}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %X{userId} [%t] -%-10c (%-L):-(%method) %m%n%throwable" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200" />
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | %X{userId} [%t] -%-10c (%-L):-(%method) %m%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <logger name="com.syb.core.manager" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="communicationLog" />
        <appender-ref ref="csvFile" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.syb.as.manager" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="communicationLog" />
        <appender-ref ref="csvFile" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.syb.ao.manager" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="communicationLog" />
        <appender-ref ref="csvFile" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="error.unhandled" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="errorFile" level="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="csvFile" />
    </logger>
    <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="debugFile" level="debug"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="errorFile" level = "error"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="infoFile"  level="info"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="info"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="csvFile" level="all"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Is there anything that could be done to enable CSV record generation in CSV files for log statements throughout the application? It would be really great if you could help.

Comment: Have you added the log4j adapters to get log messages from the old log4j lib? Have you excluded all the old log4j libs? And which version of struts do you use? The 2.5 version supports log4j2 natively.

Comment: I will check this today. Thanks. By the way I am not sure which struts version I use. I will check and let you know.